# Oracle SQL Developer showing last 90 days of data

Tags: sql, oracle

im trying to get a query working that will show the last 90 days of data. this is my timestamp code(it was a unix timestamp) :
"" to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') +
numtodsinterval(c.f_crtm,'SECOND')- 6/24  as "oracle date" ""

this is the format of my date when the above code is run: 21-JUN-2020 15:48:59

i know it has something to do with the SYSDATE -90 but i cant figure it out.
any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking of something like this:

```
(date '1970-01-01' + c.f_crtm * interval '1' second) - interval '6' hour > sysdate - interval '90' day
```

Or to use an index on `(f_crtm)`, you can rearrange the logic:

```
c.f_crtm > (trunc(sysdate - interval '90' day + interval '6 hour') - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60
```

Comment: hi Gordon thanks for the comment. im not sure where that would exactly go? are you suggesting i replace my original line of code with one of the ones you suggested? i assumed it would be a case of putting something into the where clause and not in the original select statement

Comment: @d_chawke . . . These are comparisons for the `where` clause.

Comment: ah yes that works thank you Gordon. once i run that it will only pull the last 90 days. thanks!

Comment: Consider Unix timestamps are based on `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` but `SYSDATE` might be in a different time zone. Could be important if you deal with hour values.

Comment: @d_chawke . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?